# Copy & Paste in RTE Bouncing Page

Tags: crafter-cms

There is an issue When we copy and paste text into the RTE, we can’t type in the RTE anymore without it bouncing all over the page. It moves you down the page and you have to scroll back up to get to the RTE.

While when we again type anything in RTE, Its scroll down the page on every key press.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you on?  There was a patch recently related to copy-paste and the RTE:

https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/1516

Comment: We are currently using Crafter version 2.5.10

Comment: We already have this mentioned patch as you provided.
https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/1516.

But still we have this issue for RTE.